# nav bar transition from transparent to a different background color when scrolling

Tags: html, css

i'm having some problems trying to get my nav-bar to go from being transparent at the top of the page to a different color when scrolling. I've tried a couple different methods, but it only changes when you scroll down, it doesn't change back to transparent when you scroll back up to the top.

HTML- `

```
                <ul class='link-container'>
                    <li><a href='' class='link'>Shows</a></li>
                    <li><a href='' class='link'>Merch</a></li>
                </ul>

                <a href='index.html'><img src='resources/images/logo.png' alt='Quickdraw Kid' id='logo'></a>

                <ul class='link-container'>
                    <li><a href='' class='link'>Media</a></li>
                    <li><a href='' class='link'>Booking</a></li>
                </ul>

        </nav>`
```

CSS-

```
.transparent {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.background-color {
    background-color: hsla(45, 100%, 46%, 0.8);
}

/*nav bar*/

#nav-bar {
    height: 4.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

And I tried two different ways with jQuery, one of them is currently commented out but both are below:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

/*window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
    $('#nav-bar').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 46) {
            $('#nav-bar').animate({
                backgroundColor: 'hsla(45, 100%, 46%, 0.8)'
            }, 200);
            console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        }
        else {
            $('#nav-bar').animate({
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            }, 200);
            console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        }
    });
});*/

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop > 200) {
        $('#nav-bar').addClass('transparent');
        $('#nav-bar').removeClass('background-color')
    }
    else {
        $('#nav-bar').removeClass('transparent');
        $('#nav-bar').addClass('background-color');
    }
})

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example with vanilla `JS`.

```js
const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar')

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 75) {
    navbar.classList.add('scrolled')
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove('scrolled')
  }
})
```

```css
@import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KunalTanwar/normalize/css/normalize.inter.min.css';
body {
  height: 200vh;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: background-color 250ms ease;
}

.navbar.scrolled {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar"></nav>
```